# How to create extensions for extension point by code instead of modifying in plugin.xml

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, console, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to add my own consoles in `Console View`, then I added extension for extension point `org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories` in `plugin.xml`, then create a class which extends `IConsoleFactory` (just following instruction of eclipse).

It works fine.

But now I want to create many consoles in `Console View` based on my input parameters.

Can anyone help me to create the consoles by code instead of modifying `plugin.xml`? Please help me on the code and where should we put these codes? Is it at `Activator.java` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code anywhere depending on when you want your contributions to be added. Putting it in the Activator ensures that it is done when your plugin is starting up.

For the other part of your question goto http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-dynext/ and read **Listing 2. How an extension can be added through the addContribution() API**